# iOS remove special characters from URL string

Tags: ios, urlencode, nsurlrequest

I want to call this URL using NSURLRequest:

http://www.test.com/query={"tag1":"üğişi","tag2":"çöçödd"}

These characters which are "üğişi" and "çöçödd" UTF8 character. I need to convert this URL to get response. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-(NSString*)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;` routine of th `NSString` class. Like so:

```
NSString* url = @"http://www.test.com/query={\"tag1\":\"üğişi\",\"tag2\":\"çöçödd\"}"; 
NSString* urlEncoded = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

[Here you can find more...](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744)